# Do we need 'the' here?

Tags: definite-articles

"I would like to avoid air conditioners of the office"

Do we need "the" before "air conditioners"? Because it is clear what "air conditioners" I am referring here.

Comment: Native speakers would almost certainly use ***...in** the office* in your context. And although in principle the article *(**...the** air conditioners)* needn't affect the intended meaning, personally I think in practice if it were omitted many people would understand the cited text as meaning the speaker always wants to avoid air conditioners in *any* office he happens to find himself in (whereas if it *is* included, this strongly suggests he's talking about the specific office he normally works in). But it's not really "clear" what *specific* ACs are being referenced in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean: "I would like to avoid air conditioners in the office" meaning, generally, that you would prefer not to have air conditioners in the office.

However, if you say "I would like to avoid the air conditioners in the office", that would be taken to mean specific air conditioners already in the office, and further to mean that you would avoid being near them (and especially in front of them).